# How to use reference image without copying

Tags: copyright

How to use a copyrighted image as a reference without copying

Comment: Welcome to **GDSE** - please take a look around [tour] to get a sense of who we are as a community and what we're about. Please also look at [ask] and [answer] questions to learn how to frame your query and what to expect from answers. It's also good to look at [help/behavior] to get an understanding of our community's behavioural expectations of one another. As written, your question is unclear, and may gather **VtC**s (Vote to Close) as a result; I suggest rewriting it after reviewing [ask], both to avoid closure and to help get better answers.

Comment: You **draw** freehand while merely *looking* at the reference. You *don't* trace *anything*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yousef, this is a delicate question to ask in this space, as it has copyright and moral implications too, and in the end, all of us rely on the images we produce for our income.

Please look over these previous questions very carefully and see if they help:

[Vectorizing a Skyline](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/22487/vectorizing-a-skyline/22493#22493)

[How to manipulate a photograph so that it becomes original artwork?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/79796/how-to-manipulate-a-photograph-so-that-it-becomes-original-artwork)

[Can I claim ownership of derivative Illustrations in a book?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/106885/can-i-claim-ownership-of-derivative-illustrations-in-a-book)